# How can run selenium script in chrome browser using intelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I have created simple TestNG file with simple code to open chrome browser in IntelliJ IDEA but its throwing below error, please help me.

My code:

```
public class Sample{


    @Test (priority = 0)
    public void testCase() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "mypath\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

    }
}
```

And below is Error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/remote/RenderedRemoteWebElement
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   TestCase.Sample.signIn(Sample.java:34)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)   at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RenderedRemoteWebElement   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 36 more

Answer (score 2):

Looks like something wrong is with your `selenium` client JAR - it is probably not compatible with the Chrome version you are using.

Download and use the [latest (currently 3.5.3) selenium client library](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Comment: Yes, its working fine now thanks for your valuable answer

Comment: @RajanGanesh great, glad to hear that. [Please see what you can and cannot do after you receive an answer to the question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).